# SAMBA4+DHCP+DNS Setup issue

Tags: linux, dns, samba, dhcp

I have set up `samba 4.0.9` with `bind 9.8` and `isc dhcpd 4.1.1` with flat file backend on a box running `RHEL6.4`.

Samba is able to update the DNS entries without problem. But my problem is `DHCPD` is unable to do so. I have the necessary `dnssec` key declarations in `named.conf` and `dhcpd.conf`. But it seems like, to enable samba to update the dns entries, it's own ACL policies have to be included in the `named.conf`, and samba dynamically changes the update policies in `named.conf.update` file in case another `dc` is added to the forest, so I cant hardcode to grant update right to the dhcp dns update key in the `named.conf.update` file.

And allow-update is mutually exclusive with update-policy. So if I put in `allow-update { MY_KEY };` dhcp can update the entries but samba can not. If I include the samba ACLs , `dhcpd` updates are refused. How can I have both?

Here is the zone declaration from named

```
zone "test.home.com." IN {
        type master;
        file "test.home.zone";
        check-names ignore;
    include "/usr/local/samba/private/named.conf.update";
        #allow-update { key dhcpupdatekey; };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add your `DHCPD` policies to file `/usr/local/samba/private/named.conf.update.static`. The content of this file will be included into `named.conf.update` that Samba generates, within `update-policy {}` entry.